# What does it mean to get rewards on the DAO?

Tags: tokens, the-dao

How are the reward tokens generated on the DAO?

I don't really understand. If I back a project it gets funding right? Are the managers of the project required to "give back" to the DAO if the project is very successful (economically speaking)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reward won't be tokens but Ether as I understood. DAO tokens are only used to share voting power as shares in a company. When you invest in a company, your reward is (most of the time) dollars, not shares.

Comment: ok. But what about my other question? How are the returns made?

Comment: @SilverCookies as you might now, a SE question should have only one question. So I picked up the first one. You probably should ask the other separately in new posts. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Reward tokens are created on a per proposal basis and awarded to current token holders and stay with them even if the holder Splits.  They can be claimed through *getMyReward()*

Ideally, the project the contractors develop should be what pays the DAO through *payDAO()*.  For Slockit's Universal Sharing Network, the Slock contracts themselves pay the DAO automatically whenever they are hired.  The value of that  money is added to DAO.rewards balance.

Comment: so in terms of reward it depends on the proposal itself, right?